# My sudoku board generating function is getting stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, sudoku

The user is supposed to input a number between 0 and 81, and it should generate a sudoku board with that many (valid) numbers filled in (Even if the sudoku board may not be solvable).

It works fine for small numbers of n, but if it has to backtrack, it gets stuck oscillating between ~42 and ~56.

In this program, it's important to note that n is the number that the user has specified, nOn is the number the function is on.

the array named positions[] contains the numbers 0-80 in a randomized order (compliments of the shuffle function) and is designed to represent the randomized order in which to fill the grid.

```cpp
bool Sudoku::generateSudoku(int n, int nOn)
{
    int xpos = positions[nOn] / 9;
    int ypos = positions[nOn] % 9;
    int queryCount = 0;
    char query = rand()%9 + '1';
    bool success = false;
    if (nOn >= n)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        while (queryCount < 9 && !success)
        {
            if (isValid(xpos, ypos, query, 0))
            {
                sudoku[xpos][ypos][0] = query;
                success = generateSudoku(n, nOn + 1);
            }
            if (query == '9')
            {
                query = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                query++;
            }
            queryCount++;
        }
        if (!success)
        {
            sudoku[xpos][ypos][0] = '*';
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've gone over it several times with 2 of my friends and I can't find why it's getting choked up. Any help would be appreciated!

edit: I've added a similar function that I know works for comparison. This one starts in the upper left hand corner and recursively backtracks when it runs into invalid solutions. it's able to solve any (solvable) puzzle in a matter of seconds

```cpp
int Sudoku::solveSudoku(int x, int y)
{
    bool success = false;
    char query = '1';
    int counter = 0;

    if (x == 8 && y == 9)
    {
        return 1;
        
    }
    else if (y == 9)
    {
        y = 0;
        x++;
    }

    if (sudoku[x][y][0] != '*')
    {
        sudoku[x][y][1] = sudoku[x][y][0];
        success = solveSudoku(x, y + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (query <= '9' && !success)
        {
            if (isValid(x, y, query, 1))
            {
                sudoku[x][y][1] = query;
                success = solveSudoku(x, y + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                query++;
            }
        }
        
    }
    if (success)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        sudoku[x][y][1] = sudoku[x][y][0];
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you show your friends the entire code, or just this function?  Given that it's "oscillating", perhaps the prior board configuration can never be solvable and so the program becomes stuck endlessly attempting to traverse potential valid-looking setups constructing new boards via recursion that ultimately fail.  If you think about it, each call to `generateSudoku` tries to insert 9 values.  If you're oscillating between 42 and 56 then it apparently takes 14 look-aheads to determine a value can't be placed, which means 9^14 (23 trillion) searches required before backtracking further.

Comment: You probably mean `query` rather than `querry`.

Comment: @paddy I have a similar function (uses the same recursion backtracking) that starts in the upper left hand corner and places numbers in every position, and it's able to solve any puzzle that is solvable within a matter of seconds. Why would this function be any different?

Comment: It's different because as you say, you're presented with a solvable puzzle.  In this case you're just generating random stuff at random positions.  Like I said, it could be that very early on you add a value that looks valid but will always result in an invalid board position much later.  The "much later" bit is important, because the search space of a Sudoku board is so huge, that for every additional move where you don't determine a future invalid board position, that multiplies your execution time by 9.  In other words, the time grows exponentially.